# Multiple directories with modules of a single package

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, setup.py, cythonize

I develop a Python package. Part of its modules are built via Cython. The project tree is following

```
.
├── cysrc
│   ├── aaa.py
│   └── bbb.py
├── pkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── ccc.py
│   └── ddd.py
└── setup.py
```

Modules in the `cysrc` folder goes through cythonization and compilation and ends up as `*.so` files in the wheel and in the installation.  Modules in the `pkg` folder are installed as-is (as usual Python modules).

The key lines of the `setup.py` file:

```
cy_modules = [m[:-3] for m in glob('*.py', root_dir='cysrc')] # remove extension
extensions = [Extension('mypackage.{m}', [f'cysrc/{m}.py']) for m in cy_modules]
ext_modules = cythonize(extensions, build_dir='build', compiler_directives=compiler_directives,  annotate=True)


setup(name='MyPackage',
    packages=['mypackage'],
    package_dir={'mypackage':'pkg'},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    )
```

Sometimes I need to install this package without cythonization/compilation of sources in `cysrc`. For example for usage with `converage.py` or for an editable installation.

Currently I just move files form `cysrc` to `pkg` and back when I need it. Is there more convenient way to do it?